# How can I color text in HTML without using span, div, or p

Tags: html, css

I am trying to color a word this way:

```
<span style="color: black;"><strong>2679</strong></span> pictures in <span style="color: black;"><strong>73</strong></span> albums!
```

For some reason, the second span creates a line break in the text. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all of your `<strong>` tags will have black text then use CSS to make it happen and ditch the `<span>` tags altogether:

```
strong {
    color: #000;
}
```

Or if you only want some `<strong>` tags to be black then apply a class to those:

```
strong.black {
    color: #000;
}

<strong class="black">2679</strong> pictures in <strong class="black">73</strong> albums!
```

Comment: Great idea, however not all strong tags will be black. Can I add a class to strong?